# Rails redirect on create action based on current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to redirect based on the locale.

On my controller I have:

```
  def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])
    if @inquiry.save
      redirect_to '/inquiries/thank-you'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

if user fills up the form on `fr/contact-us`

I would like to `redirect_to '/inquiries/merci'`

and if its filled up on `/contact-us`

I would like to redirect to `'/inquiries/thank-you'`

I tried:

```
if params[:inquiry][:locale] == 'fr'
 redirect_to '/fr/...'
else 
 redirect_to '/inquiries/thank-you'
```

My params looks like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"s+NlJV4QqI0UOvQNTXGc8nYFr+Ib6ZpkSvd72eKbTio=",
 "inquiry"=>{"name"=>"Beverly",
 "email"=>"bhills_0087@veryrealemail.com",
 "frame"=>"Zcaaa",
 "serial_number"=>"Lkllj",
 "subject"=>"Awgqd",
 "message"=>"Ydsgpz lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipisicing elit,
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."},
 "button"=>"",
 "locale"=>:fr}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `params[:locale]` instead of `params[:inquiry][:locale]`:

```
if params[:locale].to_s == 'fr'
```

Also, I believe you better update your `routes.rb` with something like:

```
resources :inquiry do
  collection do
     get :thank_you
  end
end
```

and use `redirect_to thank_you_inquiry_path` instead of hardcoding urls in views/controllers.